# Curly bracket issues

Tags: r, loops, curly-braces

I am assigned the task to compute the function **larger** that runs a loop through a logical variable **is_large**. Briefly, the function is meant to run through vector X and return a TRUE statement if the following number in the vector **X** is greater than the current value, and  FALSE if it is smaller and/or the last value in the vector. Aside from not knowing if the function is correct, I am having big difficulties with the bracketing.

How would I fix the bracketing, so I can do loops better in R for future instances?

```
x<-sample(1:100,10)
    
    
    larger <- function(x) {
      if x[1:,]<x[1:+1,]{
        return TRUE }
      else if x[1:,]>x[1:+1,] {
        return FALSE
        }
      else if tail((x, n=1))  {
        return FALSE
        }
      is_large <- logical(length(x))
      for (i in 1:nrow(x)){
        is_larger[i,] <- x[i,]
      } return(is_large)
    }
```

Comment: @IRTFM why use an if at all, since `if(sign(diff()) == 1) TRUE else FALSE` is just a long way of writing `sign(diff()) == 1`

Comment: The `if` function always needs parentheses around the logical test. And why not use sign(diff()) == 1 with a single if (.){ TRUE} else {FALSE}`, Or use ifelse which wouldn’t require an additional loop construct.

Comment: Fair point Allan. If this is to be used to modify a dataframe there may need to be padding. To Kash: for homework questions there should be further [edit] efforts on your part.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you know that R do not stop executing a line if it finds that you break the line in such a way that code is not finished.
as a example :

```
data %>% 
mutate(c=sum(Total))
```

Even though you break the line R quickly go to the next line to fetch the rest of the code.

when curly brackets are placed, you necessarily do not need to break the lines as above. you could break anywhere and code run as a BLOCK

```
    larger <- function(x) {
 What ever you write here consider as a one block
        }
```